# Mac OS X 10.6/python/pyperclip

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pip, pyperclip

I'm trying to pick up python via Al Sweigart's book Automate the Boring Stuff and have ran into an issue getting pyperclip to properly install, or even pip for that matter on my machine running OS X 10.6.

How do I know pip is installed?

I ran the sudo pip install in the terminal last night.

I'm trying to run http://pastebin.com/2aEPV45Y.

What steps can I take to

1. make sure pip has installed and is running and
2. get pyperclip to run properly when I begin a program with "import pyperclip"?

Answer (score 2):

If you installed python3 from python.org, use pip3 to install version 3 modules.

Comment: This is the right answer. I am surprised it was downvoted